# Set input on disabled based on a variable

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, input

Having a normal input form it's straightforward to make it disabled:

```
<input
  {...field}
  as={Input}
  disabled={disableInput}
  className="my-class"
  placeholder="write data"
  value={...}
/>
```

But how can this be done if the input has a different structure like:

```
  <input
    {...getInputProps({
      placeholder: 'write data',
      className: 'my-class',
    })}
  />
```

I've tried several ways but didn't work. One way was to add disabled attribute on top level, other approach was to add it inside getInputProps, none of them work.

```
  <input
    disabled={disableInput}
    {...getInputProps({
      placeholder: 'write data',
      className: 'my-class',
    })}
  />
```

or

```
  <input       
    {...getInputProps({
      disabled={disableInput}
      placeholder: 'write data',
      className: 'my-class',
    })}
  />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the value of disableInput? And also include the function`getInputProps`.

Comment: @SarunUK it is a boolean, so it's `true` or `false`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `disabled: disableInput` in the last variant?

Comment: @ThomasKuhlmann you're right. it works like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Thomas Kuhlman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9396266/thomas-kuhlmann)n's comment. the solution is to add the disabled attribute inside but not like `disabled={disabledInput}`. The correct way is `disabled: disabledInput`.

```
  <input       
    {...getInputProps({
      disabled: disabledInput
      placeholder: 'write data',
      className: 'my-class',
    })}
  />
```